# Não consigo testar meu componente react

Tags: react, typescript, testes, jest, react-testing-library

Quero testar se uma função está sendo chamada quando o formulário é enviado, mas não consigo fazer isso.

```
// UsersContext.tsx
import { User } from "@/types/global";
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

// create context
export const UserContext = createContext<any>({});

export const UserProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [nome, setNome] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);

  const addUser = ({ nome, email }: User) => {
    const newUser = { nome, email };
    setUsers([...users, newUser]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    addUser({ nome, email });
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        nome,
        setNome,
        email,
        setEmail,
        users,
        addUser,
        handleSubmit,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

My hook:

```
// useUsers.tsx
import { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "@/contexts/UsersContext";

const useUsers = () => useContext(UserContext);

export default useUsers;
```

My form:

```
// UseForm.tsx
import React from "react";
import useUsers from "@/hooks/useUsers";

const UserForm = () => {
  const { nome, setNome, email, setEmail, handleSubmit } = useUsers();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="containerForm">
        <div className="titleForm">
          <h1>Formulário</h1>
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="boxField flex-col flex">
            <label htmlFor="nome">Nome</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={nome}
              id="nome"
              onChange={(e) => setNome(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="boxField flex-col flex">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              value={email}
              id="email"
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <button>Add User</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default UserForm;
```

My test:

```
// UseForm.spec.tsx
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import user from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { UserContext } from "@/contexts/UsersContext";
import UserForm from "./UserForm";

describe("Testando UserForm", () => {
  test("it calls addUser when the form is submitted", () => {
    const mockAddUser = jest.fn();

    render(
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ addUser: mockAddUser }}>
        <UserForm />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );

    // encontra dois inputs
    const [nameInput, emailInput] = screen.getAllByRole("textbox");

    // simula a digitação de um nome
    user.click(nameInput);
    user.keyboard("felipesa");

    // simula a digitação de um email
    user.click(emailInput);
    user.keyboard("felipesas@gmail.com");

    // encontra o botão
    const submitButton = screen.getByRole("button");

    // simula o clique no botão
    user.click(submitButton);

    expect(mockAddUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockAddUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      nome: "felipesa",
      email: "felipesas@gmail.com",
    });
  });
});
```

O jest retorna o mesmo erro

[A imagem está aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUnHh.png)

Como posso testar se a função addUser está sendo chamada e se os usuários do estado têm as informações registradas?

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta substituindo o código apresentado por um [mcve] de um problema objetivo e pontual, com uma explicação da dificuldade para avançar. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor proveito do site.

Answer (score -3):

O erro tá acontecendo porque você tá passando um objeto com a propriedade "mockAddUser" pro contexto do UserContext, mas na verdade o nome da função é apenas "addUser". Pra consertar o erro, você precisa passar o nome certo da função pro contexto.

E outra coisa, você tá testando se a função "mockAddUser" foi chamada ao invés de "addUser", entendeu?? Pra testar se a função "addUser" foi chamada, você tem que passar ela pro contexto do UserContext em vez de "mockAddUser".

**Teste**

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import UserForm from "./UserForm";
import user from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { UserContext } from "@/contexts/UsersContext";

describe("Test UseForm", () => {

  test("it calls addUser when the form is submitted", () => {
    const mockAddUser = jest.fn();

    render(
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ addUser: mockAddUser }}>
        <UserForm />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );

    // encontra dois inputs
    const [nameInput, emailInput] = screen.getAllByRole("textbox");

    // simula a digitação de um nome
    user.click(nameInput);
    user.keyboard("felipesa");

    // simula a digitação de um email
    user.click(emailInput);
    user.keyboard("felipesas@gmail.com");

    // encontra o botão
    const submitButton = screen.getByRole("button");

    // simula o clique no botão
    user.click(submitButton);

    expect(mockAddUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockAddUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      nome: "felipesa",
      email: "felipesas@gmail.com",
    });
  });
});
```

**As alterações realizadas foram:**

- Corrigir o nome da função "addUser" no objeto passado para o contexto
  do UserContext.
- Alterar o nome da variável de "mockAddUser" para "addUser" para
  refletir a função correta.
- Testar se a função "addUser" foi chamada em vez de "mockAddUser".

Comment: Opa mano, boa noite. Primeiramente, muito obrigado pela resposta. Porém eu ajeitei aqui o meu arquivo de teste e dá o mesmo erro mano. Atualizei minha postagem com o código de teste que vc mandou e mais uma imagem mostrando o erro. Sabe o que pode ser?